# Quando usar uma unique constraints vs indices únicos no Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

Existe algum tipo de boa prática e/ou recomendação na hora de criar índices únicos vs *constraints* no Oracle?

Quando devo usar um e quando devo usar o outro?

Existe alguma situação em que eu deva usar os dois?

```sql
ALTER TABLE t ADD CONSTRAINT t_c1_c2_unq UNIQUE (c1, c2);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX t_c1_c2_unq_idx ON t(c1, c2);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Unicidade dos dados

Para garantir a unicidade dos dados, não há diferença prática na maioria dos casos. Uma *unique constraint* é quase sempre implementada como um *unique index*, e um *unique index* impede que você tenha valores repetidos (funcionando portanto, como uma *unique constraint*).

Recomenda-se, no entanto, que sempre que você precisar de um índice por questões de performance, você [crie o índice explicitamente](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:36858373078604) (para cobrir os casos em que o índice não é criado pela *constraint*).

### Chave estrangeira

Por fim, se você quiser referenciar uma coluna (ou conjunto de colunas) em uma chave estrangeira, essa(s) coluna(s) deve(m) ter uma *unique constraint*. No exemplo abaixo, a segunda chave estrangeira não pode ser criada, pois referencia uma coluna que não possui uma *unique constraint* (apesar de ter um índice único).

```sql
CREATE TABLE cons(
  id NUMBER, 
  CONSTRAINT cons_cons UNIQUE (id));

CREATE TABLE ind(id NUMBER);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ind_ind on ind(id);

-- OK. Chave estrangeira referencia coluna
-- com CONSTRAINT UNIQUE.
CREATE TABLE fk_cons(
  fk NUMBER, 
  CONSTRAINT fk1 FOREIGN KEY(fk) REFERENCES cons(id));

-- Erro: para ser referenciado por uma chave estrangeira,
-- ind(id) deve ser PRIMARY KEY ou ter CONSTRAINT UNIQUE.
CREATE TABLE fk_ind(
  fk NUMBER, 
  CONSTRAINT fk2 FOREIGN KEY(fk) REFERENCES ind(id));
```

Fontes: https://forums.oracle.com/thread/1033157 e https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7521817/oracle-unique-constraint-and-unique-index-question

Comment: por favor, tenho mais duvidas que a sua resposta infelizmente não contemplou, não posso fazer outra pergunta porque o pessoal marca como duplicado... então por favor, pode me ajudar e complementar explicando como é funcionamento de manutenção de um *indice Unique vs UK constraint*, o comportamento na validação do dado e possibilidade de "atrasar" a validação dos dados em uma transação? (para melhor entendimento veja aqui a [mesma pergunta para o Mysql](http://br.stackoverflow.com/questions/793/diferenca-na-utilizacao-indice-unique-e-unique-constraint-no-mysql))